# Netbeans and SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server, netbeans

I am very new to Netbeans and PHP / HTML development - I am trying to teach myself. I have MS SQL server installed and running on my machine. I am struggling to connect Netbeans project to a database in SQL server. I have tried to search for the driver and install it, but I just can't get it to work. Anyone with some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: There are simiral questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892783/connecting-to-sql-server-from-netbeans and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32729099/connecting-netbeans-8-0-2-to-microsoft-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I have downloaded the driver, I have tried to connect, but I still receive an error. Should I paste a screen shot of the variables I'm using to try and connect?